# Вывести текст из TextBox в базу данных Access

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio, ms-access, textbox

подскажите пожалуйста, никак не получается сделать следующее: Есть 6 textBox с информацией типа string (первые 5: ФИО, Почта, Номер, Номер_паспорта, Номер_рейса) и последнее поле int (Кол-во_мест). Нужно значения из этих 6ти TextBox'ов вывести в соответствующие поля таблицы базы данных Access. Таблица называется ticket, БД - db

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с похожей задачей, подскажите, пожалуйста!(

Comment: Откройте документацию, там есть примеры.

Comment: Какую документацию?

Comment: По технологиям, с которыми вы работаете

Comment: [пример получения данных из СУБД Access](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32d09f7e-4efa-4fad-9a64-2bb91c23ea21/cselect-data-from-access?forum=csharpgeneral)